# How can I make a button toggle with Unity's new Input System?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, toggle

I've been trying to make the player able to crouch by pressing a button once to crouch, and again to stand.

I thought this would be pretty simple and I could just use a bool, but it seems like when the button to crouch is pressed, it's giving input too fast and immediately uncrouching. I'm not sure if I'm getting my bool from the wrong place or what.

This is what I have to toggle crouch.

```
//CROUCH
if (crouch.IsPressed() && !isCrouching)
{
    Crouch();
}

if(crouch.IsPressed()  && isCrouching )
{
    Stand();
}
```

These are the methods being called to crouch/stand. I'm thinking my problem has to do with setting my bool in these, but I can't figure it out.

```
void Crouch()
{
    isCrouching = true;
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, 0.75f, transform.localScale.z);
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 0.15f, transform.position.z);
}

void Stand()
{
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, 1f, transform.localScale.z);
    isCrouching = false;
}
```

Also to be clear this is inside FixedUpdated. Not sure if that has an effect either, but when I tried normal update it was the same.

Comment: Could you add an "else" infront of the second if statement, so you do not have two separate if statements. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I added the "else" in front of the second if statement, and now I can sort of crouch. The player still jitters up and down when I press the key, but it is able to crouch and stand if I time it right. Also worth mentioning the crouch/stand is smooth when the button isn't a toggle, so it seems like both statements are still being triggered somehow.

Comment: Problem was you set is crouching in the first and then checked if pressed and crouching and undid it.

Comment: That's exactly what it's supposed to be doing though. Is there some other way I should be doing this?

Comment: Okay well using debug.log I can see the statement is read as true 10 times during one button press. That's probably a problem and I'm not sure how to stop that. I can hardly understand this new system.

Comment: I changed the "crouch.IsPressed()" to "crouch.WasPressedThisFrame()" and that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:
Use [WasPressedThisFrame](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.4/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_InputAction_WasPressedThisFrame) instead to get a bool which is only true one frame.
And you should change your code to an if else statement so they can not be both true after one another in the same frame.